# White wine vinegar query

Tags: vinegar

How long does white wine vinegar last if kept in a sealed bottle? Does this apply to the age of all vinegars kept in a sealed bottle?

Answer (score 3):

For white vinegar: basically forever.

Vinegar is acidic, so most bacteria won't grow in it. Plain white vinegar in a sealed container will keep longer than you'll be around to use it.

Some vinegars (balsamic, wine vinegar, etc) can experience flavor changes & other undesirable effects when exposed to air, light, or extreme temperatures. Stored in a sealed container in a cool, dark place, they will keep for a very long time--but not always forever.

Comment: Most bacteria? You mean there is some bacteria that can survive and kill you? Or do you mean all bacteria?

Comment: @Rob I'm not a scientist nor a doctor, but I assume there's some vinegar resistant super bacteria out there. Probably lurking in the salad dressing you had with lunch.